# Optimal sphere packings ==> Thinnest ball coverings?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, sphere-packing

It was proved by Kershner long ago that the thinnest (least density)
covering of the plane by congruent disks can be obtained
by enlarging the radii of the optimal circle packing to just cover
the gaps in that packing:

---

[image: CoverDisks]

---

My question is:

> ***Q***. Is it known that, in the dimensions for which the optimal sphere packing
>   is known $(2, 3, 8, 24)$, is it also known that a thinnest ball covering can be achieved
>   by enlarging the spheres to just cover the interstices in the packing?

For example, now that the Kepler problem has been settled by Hales,
does it follow that a thinnest ball packing of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be
obtained from the cannonball packing by enlarging the spheres to just cover
the gaps?

---

[image: CoverBalls]

---

> <sup>Kershner, Richard. "The number of circles covering a set." *American Journal of Mathematics* 61.3 (1939): 665-671.</sup>

Comment: Is there an application for this (packaging golf balls?) or is it theoretical?

Comment: @cat: Error-correcting codes; modeling granular structures; stacking oranges. :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Nope, this is false in three dimensions (where the body-centered cubic beats the face-centered cubic for covering) and eight dimensions (where $E_8$ is [not even locally optimal](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405441)). The Leech lattice is locally optimal and may be the best covering in twenty-four dimensions, but that would be a special fact rather than an instance of a general pattern. Overall sphere covering is more complicated than sphere packing, and there seems to be no close relationship between the optimal solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledgeable (and surprising) answer!

Comment: Schuermann and Vallentin wrote several fascinating papers on the covering problem about a decade ago, including the one I linked to in the answer. I'm still amazed that $E_8$ isn't locally optimal, and it makes me wary of trying to intuit the answers to high-dimensional optimization problems.