# Terrible tilers for covering the plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, tiling, sphere-packing

Let $C$ be a convex shape in the plane.
Your task is to cover the plane with copies of $C$, each under any rigid motion.
My question is essentially: What is the worst $C$, the shape that forces the most
wasteful overlap?

To be more precise, assume $C$ has unit area.
Let $n_C(A)$ be the fewest copies of $C$ (under any rigid motions) that suffice to cover a disk
of area $A$. I seek the $C$ that maximizes the "waste":
$$ w(C) = \lim_{A \to \infty} n_C(A) / A \;.$$
So if $C$ is a perfect tiler of the plane, then $\lim_{A \to \infty} n_C(A) = A$
(because $C$ has area $1$)
and $w(C)=1$, i.e., no waste.

Consider a regular pentagon $P$, which cannot tile the plane. Here is one way
to cover the plane with regular pentagons:

---

[image: TilerPentagon]

---

If I've calculated correctly, this arrangement shows that $w(P) \le 1.510$.
So one could cover an area $A=100$ with about $151$ unit-area regular pentagons,
a $51$% waste.
I doubt this is the best way to cover the plane with copies of $P$ (***Q3*** below), but it is one
way.

Three questions.

> ***Q1***. Is it known that the disk is the worst shape $C$ to cover the plane?
>   My understanding is that L.F.Tóth's paper[1], which I have not accessed,
>   establishes this for *lattice* tilings/coverings. Is it known for arbitrary coverings?

*Q1 Answered*. Thanks to several, and especially Yoav Kallus, for pointing me
in the right direction. Q1 remains an open problem. In [2,p.15], what I call
the waste of a convex body $C$ is called $\theta(C)$. It is about $1.209$ for a disk. The best upperbound is $\theta(C) \le 1.228$ due to Dan Ismailescu,
based on finding special tiling "p-hexagons" in $C$. A p-hexagon has two 
opposite, parallel edges of the same length.

> ***Q2***. Since every triangle, and every quadrilateral, tiles the plane,
>   the first interesting polygonal shape is pentagons.
>   What is the most wasteful pentagon?
>
> ***Q3***. More specifically, what is the waste $w(P)$ for the regular pentagon?

---

[1]
L. Fejes Tóth, "Lagerungen in der Ebene auf der Kugel und im Raum." 
*Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften* Vol. 65. Springer-Verlag, 1972. doi:[10.1007/978-3-642-65234-9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65234-9)

[2]
Brass, Peter, William OJ Moser, and János Pach. *Research Problems in Discrete Geometry*. Springer Science & Business Media, 2006.

Comment: How about a house? (Square plus triangle) Gerhard "Welcome To The Suburban Future" Paseman, 2016.12.03.

Comment: Oh wait. That tiles. Maybe with a weird roof?  Gerhard "Not Yet A City Planner" Paseman, 2016.12.03.

Comment: Any pentagon with two parallel sides tiles the plane.  (See for instance the first picture in http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2YKhXVT62rc/Vd2KGHpYwnI/AAAAAAAAGWU/6Rw5Dn_tTIY/s1600/type-1-15-byEd%2BPegg.jpg)

Comment: However, you can use these good tilers to estimate the ratio. Pick a good tiler nearest the shape of the bad tiler and embed a scaled down copy into the bad tiler. The best scale factor among many choices should allow a good estimate of the waste factor.  Gerhard "It Is Like Urban Renewal" Paseman, 2016.12.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Yes. And the lack of understanding of which are the perfect pentagonal tilers is an impediment to answering Q2.

Comment: I imagine so.  However, a general version of Q3 seems to be equivalent to "What is the area of the largest good (maybe convex)  tiler contained entirely inside a bad convex tiler?".  Even if it is not equivalent, I think it would make a good Q4.  Gerhard "Consider It A Holiday Gift" Paseman, 2016.12.03.

Comment: As an example of **Gerhard Paseman**'s recent comments, we get a waste ratio of
only $w = (5+\sqrt{80})/11 < 1.2676611$ (if I computed right) for regular
pentagons $P$ by finding a pentagon $P' \subset P$ of area $|P|/w$
that has two parallel sides and thus tiles the plane: fix a side $s$ of $P$,
and let $P'$ consist of all points of $P$ that project to a point of $s$.

Comment: Indeed.  One can use Noam Elkies's projection method to establish a quick upper bound for the waste. Perhaps by perturbing good tilers in known ways, one can carve out a selection of so-so tilers and reduce the search space for bad tilers significantly. Not a Q2 answer, but definitely clearing away the examples that won't work.  Maybe asking Q2 for a Pentagon three of whose sides match a good tiler? Gerhard "Using This Mostly For Good" Paseman, 2016.12.03.

Comment: Great question - I wonder if it's equivalent to the one of what convex shape(s) pack the plane (in the sphere sense) with the lowest density. Obviously they're equivalent at the other end - zero waste is equal to perfect density - but that wouldn't a priori imply equivalence for the worst-case scenarios.

Comment: I want to edit the reference to give more info (L. Fejes Tóth, "Lagerungen in der Ebene auf der Kugel und im Raum.", Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften Vol. 65. Springer-Verlag, 1972. <http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65234-9>) but you wrote 2013, which makes me pause. Is that a second edition? EDIT hmm, no 2nd ed was apparently 1972...

Comment: ...And you wrote 'paper' not 'book', dated after he died!

Comment: Here is an article about the dual problem, densest packing of regular pentagons in the plane: http://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2014/12/01/packing-regular-pentagons/

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I asked earlier a question that addressed the relationship between tiling and covering ([Optimal sphere packings ==> Thinnest ball coverings?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/251604/6094)). The conclusion was that they are rather different.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Thanks for the correction. I relied (mindlessly) on Google scholar.

Comment: If 1) the disc is the worst shape for lattice coverings and 2) the best covering for the disc is a lattice covering, then the disc is the worst shape overall (because the lattice covering of a disc is worse than the lattice covering for each other shape, hence worse than the best covering for each other shape). Presumably 2 is known?

Comment: Could some results on [this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=E3-BheG-CoYC&pg=PA29&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) be useful (this is p. 29 in Pach, Agarwal, _Combinatorial Geometry_)?

Comment: What is known about the most economic covering of the plane by regular pentagons? That is, bounding $w(P )$ from below.

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit to fix the link syntax for the Toth book. What was in my comment was missing the `http://`!

Comment: @PietroMajer: That is essentially my Q3. I don't know. Likely explored in the past, but I haven't located bounds.

Comment: To get an upper bound on $w(C )$, one could consider any shape $T\subset C$  that can form a tassellation of the plane, like the square inside the pentagon in the picture, and argue analogously. Is there e.g. a good hexagon prototile in $P$? The square seems close to optimal, though.

Comment: @PietroMajer: See Noam Elkies remarks. He fit a "house" pentagon inside a regular pentagon, knowing that the former tiles the plane.

Comment: So a variation could be: let's remove the roof of Noam's house $P'$, but restore the two lateral pieces in $P\setminus P'$. The resulting hexagons make a tassellation of the plane as well.

Comment: This way I got exactly $w(P )\le5/4=1.25$

Comment: re:Q1, Brass, Moser, and Pach have a good summary of results in their book https://books.google.com/books?id=cT7TB20y3A8C&lpg=PR1&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=least%20economical%20convex%20sets%20for%20covering&f=false

Comment: Question Q1 is indeed answered by L. Fejes Tóth in [1] (btw it's a book, not a paper) in the positive for all crossing-free coverings, and it is conjectured that the "crossing-free" assumption is not needed.

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg: I'm not sure I understand your comment, and would like you to clarify. As I read it, you are saying that every domain permits a crossing-free covering no denser than $1.209$. It follows that every domain permits a covering no denser than $1.209$. So, the "crossing-free" qualification is unnecessary. What did I get wrong?

Comment: @YoavKallus: Of course, you're right, I made a mistake. The circle is known to be the worst for covering among centrally symmetric convex disks. In general, it is still an open problem.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a better (possibly best) way of covering the plane with congruent regular pentagons:

---

[image: PentCover]

---

The density of this covering is ${\sqrt5}/2 = 1.1180...$.
This covering is generated by the maximum-area $p$-hexagon contained in $P$, and is the thinnest among all coverings with $P$ that are of the *double-lattice* type. **I conjecture that this density is minimum among all coverings with $P$, not just double-lattice ones.**

For the notion of double-lattice see: Kuperberg, G.; Kuperberg, W. (1990), *Double-lattice packings of convex bodies in the plane*, Discrete and Computational Geometry, 5 (4): 389–397, MR 1043721

This covering is obtained by a continuous transition starting with the best packing with regular pentagons, see
http://www.auburn.edu/~kuperwl/pent_movie.mp4

Comment: Do you know if it is known---or considered likely---that the regular pentagon is the worst pentagon for covering? (Of course the regular hexagon tiles, so regularity is no universal guide.)

Comment: If you "raise the roof", so that the overlapping triangle is enlarged when the top two sides are made longer (but leave the other three as is), you get more waste for this type of packing of the new Pentagon (which goes back to my house comment). You might even get halfway to the waste ratio for the circle .  Gerhard "Has To Come Full Circle" Paseman, 2016.12.05.

Comment: Joe: As far as I know - no, but yes, I do think that the regular pentagon is the worst pentagon for covering. Some of its affine images may be equally bad, though.

Comment: No. "Raising the roof" does not make the pentagon worse; it makes it better. Namely, in the modified pentagon one can use a different corner for the overlap; most efficiently the one at which the angle is greatest.

Comment: For some people orange and green colors, of similar darkness, flash and get confused with each other... Otherwise great answer!

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: colors changed in the picture; working on the animation.

Comment: Actually this is precisely the covering I suggested in my last comment to the question; my computation was  $w(P )\le5/4$

Comment: @PietroMajer: that's correct. But my computation was $\sqrt{5/4}$, and in the picture the clipped off tip looks indeed smaller than $1/5$ of the pentagon's area.

Comment: yes, 5/4 is a quick bound for w(P ), based on Area(clipped off tip)<1/5 :)