# Which pentagon gives least packing density?

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling, packing-and-covering

We extend [Which convex pentagon gives least packing density?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398115/which-convex-pentagon-gives-least-packing-density) by going from convex pentagons to general ones.

**Question:** Which pentagon gives the least packing density on the Euclidean plane?

**Note:** All quadrilaterals (convex or otherwise) are perfect tiles - in Euclidean plane. And it seems one can form non-convex *hexagons* with arbitrarily low packing density. So, the present question might be non-trivial only for pentagons.