# Facility location on manifolds

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control

**Facility location** studies optimal placement of a certain number $n$ of points (facilities) in some region $R$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem)

The **minimax** facility location problem finds $n$ locations in $R$ for the facility points such that: if $P$ is any point in $R$ and $d(P)$ is the distance from $P$ to the closest facility point, then the highest value of $d(P)$ as $P$ ranges over $R$ is minimized.

The **dispersal** problem places $n$ points in $R$ such that the minimum pair-wise distance among them is maximized.

**Question:** Is this claim true: "If the region $R$ is a closed and homogeneous manifold (such as a sphere or $S^1 \times S^1$) with a metric, then, for any $n$, if a given configuration of $n$ facility points solves one of the above problems, then, it automatically solves the other problem for that $n$"?

If the claim holds, does its converse also hold — "if both above problems have same answer for any $n$ in some $R$, then, $R$ is a closed and homogeneous manifold"?

Note: The earlier version of the post had a confused formulation of the maximin problem. Now, maximin has been replaced by dispersion.

Comment: I suppose that $R$ is a Riemannian manifold, not a Finsler manifold?

Comment: As to the type of manifolds being considered being wider than Riemannian - I would request experts to decide.

Comment: Thank you. Made one more attempt to get the problem statement in order.

Comment: Thanks; now the question is clear.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is *No*, the claim is not true.
At least not if my reformulation of the question is correct.

What the OP calls dispersion is usually viewed as optimal packing
of $n$ congruent circles, also known as the Tammes problem
(e.g., [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/212550/6094) MO question).

The OP's minimax facility location problem I believe can be viewed
as optimal *cover* by congruent disks, with the distance from any
point $p \in R$ to a facility at most the radius of a covering disk.

So the OP's question is essentially:

> Is the best packing configuration also the best covering configuration?

In the plane this is true, a result of Richard Kershner from 1939.
So the OP's question is a natural extension.

Here is why I think that in more general situations, the claim is false.
Consider packing and covering the flat square torus by congruent circles/disks. There has been considerable work on the packing question,
a variant of the Tammes problem. There has been much less work on covering.
However, the two papers cited below indicate that the optimal configurations are not the same for $n=3$.

First the optimal packing. Note the asymmetry:

[image: Torus3Pack]

Next the optimal cover. Note the symmetry.

[image: Torus3Cover]

I could be misinterpreting these two papers, but if not, then
they provide an example showing the optimal packing and covering
configurations are, in general, not identical.

> Brandt, Madeline, William Dickinson, AnnaVictoria Ellsworth, Jennifer Kenkel, and Hanson Smith. "Optimal packings of two to four equal circles on any flat torus." *Discrete Mathematics* 342, no. 12 (2019): 111597. [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2019.111597).

> Joós, Antal. "On covering the square flat torus by congruent discs." *Australasian J. Combinatorics* 75, no. 1 (2019): 113-126.
> [PDF download](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/75/ajc_v75_p113.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and the quite surprising (conjectured) answer - quite hard to accept that the two questions can have different answers. Maybe same is the case even on a sphere. Maybe there are parallels to an earlier discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251604/optimal-sphere-packings-thinnest-ball-coverings

Comment: Yes, I think packing and covering on a sphere are not always identical, but I could not identify proven cases where they are known to differ. Partly because there are few proven cases.

Comment: Re that earlier question about thinnest ball covers: See especially [Henry Cohn's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/251608/6094): "Overall sphere covering is more complicated than sphere packing, and there seems to be no close relationship between the optimal solutions."

Comment: Reg the mapping of maximin to covering and dispersion to packing, is the *equal sized disks* condition obvious? for best dispersion, should every site have same distance to its closest site? To give a different example, pls see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376672/cutting-convex-regions-into-equal-diameter-and-equal-least-width-pieces-2. There it was noted that "f maximum (minimum) area among n convex pieces is to be minimized (maximized), then, it is easy to see all pieces should have same area." but that similar statements are not obvious for quantities such as perimeter, diameter,...

Comment: @NandakumarR: Consider packing equal disks in a circle. For $n=20$, the conjectured optimal packing has one disk (in the center) that doesn't touch any others. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle). This is the general situation: the contact graph need not be connected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that nice example! And it seems even if one replaces the big circle being tiled with a manifold such as a real projective plane, the packing behavior might be similar.  So the claim of an optimal dispersion arrangement being an optimal maximin one too *might not* hold for all n even on manifolds that are both *homogeneous and isotropic* .