# Bounds for minimax facility location in a convex region

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

An earlier question: [Facility location on manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391915/facility-location-on-manifolds?noredirect=1&lq=1)

A possibly related earlier post: [Cutting convex regions into equal diameter and equal least width pieces - 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376672/cutting-convex-regions-into-equal-diameter-and-equal-least-width-pieces-2)

The minimax facility location problem finds $n$ locations in some domain $R$ for the facility points such that: if $P$ is any point in $R$ and $d(P$) is the distance from $P$ to the closest facility point, then the highest value of $d(P)$ as $P$ ranges over $R$ is minimized.

Let us assign each point on $R$ to that facility point closest to it, Define $D(i)$ as the maximum distance to the $i$-th facility from among points on $R$ assigned to that facility.

**Question:** If $R$ is a convex region of unit diameter and $n$ facility points are to be located within it, what is the upper bound on the *variation* in $D(i)$ (say, the ratio of the largest value to the smallest) in a solution of the minimax problem? Which shape of $R$ achieves this bound? What is the dependency of this variation on $n$ and dimensionality of $R$?

I know of no example where $D(i)$ shows variation over $i$ in an optimal solution to the minimax location problem.

**Note:** An analogous question can also be asked with a road network replacing the convex region,  distances between points on the network being path lengths and each network point assigned to the closest facility point. The p-median problem might be related.

Comment: Could you please define "the variation in ()"? An example might help.

Comment: Thank you. Made an edit. Actually, I don't know any case (even in 2D with small values of n) where any optimal solution of the minimax location problem necessarily shows any difference among the D(i) values.