# Bounds for the Dispersal Problem in convex regions

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

We add a bit to: [Bounds for minimax facility location in a convex region](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455309/bounds-for-minimax-facility-location-in-a-convex-region)

Two earlier posts:  [Cutting convex regions into equal diameter and equal least width pieces - 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376672/cutting-convex-regions-into-equal-diameter-and-equal-least-width-pieces-2) and [Facility location on manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391915/facility-location-on-manifolds?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Definitions:** The *dispersal problem* places $n$ points ('facilities') in a region $R$ such that the minimum pair-wise distance among them is maximized. In an optimal solution with $n$ facilities, let $D(i)$ be the distance from the $i$-th facility to the facility closest to it.

**Question:** If $R$ is a convex region and if $n$ facility points have been placed in it to achieve optimal dispersal, will all values of $D(i)$ be necessarily equal? If not, what is the upper bound of the ratio between the max value of $D(i)$ and the min value as a function of say, the shape of $R$, the dimensionality of $R$ and $n$?

Comment: If $n=8$ and $R$ is the unit circle, having 7 equally spaced points on the circle and one in the center is optimal (from circle packing in a circle), which falsifies the first question. In general, the question is equivalent to asking how isolated a circle can be in an optimal circle packing.

Comment: Thanks. i suspect the mapping to circle packing is not quite straightforward because if a facility is put on the boundary of R, only a fraction of a disk centered there will be inside R. Yes, I tend to agree with your conclusion that it is *not necessary* that all facility points in an optimal solution (one that maximizes least separation among them) are at the *same* least distance from the closest facility. and could you give an *answer* which has something on the upper bound asked in the question?